# How to compute the partial derivatives of the function $L = Y_{ijk} \cdot (X_i(W_j-W_k)^\top)$

Tags: derivatives

If $L = Y_{ijk} \cdot (X_i(W_j-W_k)^\top)$ then what will be the partial derivative of $L$ with respect to $W_j^\top$ and $W_k^\top$ respectively?

Are the below solutions correct?

1. $L'(W_j^\top) = 2X_i^\top(X_i(W_j-W_k)^\top-Y_{ijk})$ if $Y_{ijk}X_i(W_j-W_k)^\top \leq 1$ else $L'(W_j^\top)=0$
2. $L'(W_k^\top) = -2X_i^\top(X_i(W_j-W_k)^\top-Y_{ijk})$ if $Y_{ijk}X_i(W_j-W_k)^\top \leq 1$ else $L'(W_k^\top)=0$